# How to make Option classes like GUILayoutOption?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm wondering how to make a class similar to GUILayoutOption class where it would take a whole bunch of GUILayout's static fields as parameters.

I couldn't find my answer in Unity Docs and I was wondering if somebody has made such a construct before.

I'm trying to make something like this:

`public void SomeMethod( params MyClassOption[] options )`

and call it for example like this: `SomeMethod(MyClass.AnimationClip(aniClipRef), MyClass.AnimationDuration(duration), MyClass.StopAllOtherAnimations);`

Seems like a great and clean way to wrap code with dozens of potentially optional parameters, but I'm not sure how to define it. Can somebody write a minimalistic example or explain how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find stuff like these in the documentation or any tutorial. If you are curious on how something is implemented, use decompiler such as **.NET Reflector** and you will see how each class is implemented.

Below is a minimalist example of how to do this. *Do not use this*. This is only here to show *exactly* how this is done by Unity. It uses the `param` keyword and performs boxing, both which allocates memory.

**Example:**

```
MyClass.Button("Submit Button", MyClass.MinWidth(10), MyClass.MaxWidth(20),
             MyClass.MinHeight(10), MyClass.MaxHeight(10));
```

---

*The `MyClassOption` class:*

```
public class MyClassOption
{
    public Type type;
    public object value;

    public MyClassOption(Type type, object value)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public enum Type
    {
        minWidth,
        maxWidth,
        minHeight,
        maxHeight,
    }
}
```

*The `MyClass` class:*

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static bool Button(string text, params MyClassOption[] options)
    {
        return showButton(text, options);
    }

    private static bool showButton(string text, MyClassOption[] options)
    {
        //Not IMPLEMENTED
        //DISPLAY BUTTON THEN CHECK IF IT IS CLICKED?
        return false;
    }

    public static MyClassOption MaxHeight(float maxHeight)
    {
        return new MyClassOption(MyClassOption.Type.maxHeight, maxHeight);
    }

    public static MyClassOption MaxWidth(float maxWidth)
    {
        return new MyClassOption(MyClassOption.Type.maxWidth, maxWidth);
    }

    public static MyClassOption MinHeight(float minHeight)
    {
        return new MyClassOption(MyClassOption.Type.minHeight, minHeight);
    }

    public static MyClassOption MinWidth(float minWidth)
    {
        return new MyClassOption(MyClassOption.Type.minWidth, minWidth);
    }
}
```

Basically, you add your custom options in the `enum` from the `MyClassOption` class then you add a function that will be used to access that `enum` in the `MyClass`. That function will return new `MyClassOption` object.

There's too much memory allocation going on each time an option is added to a function or executed to the extent that I think it is not worth it. It is fine in a normal C# application but not in a game app which can cause hiccups due to *GC*.

**EDIT:**

Things that can be done to improve this:

**1**.Change the `MyClassOption` class to `struct`.

**2**.On the `MyClassOption` class constructor `object value` parameter, change that to c# generics. `T[] value`.

Now, the only problem left is the `param` keyword which is the only thing that allocates memory. It should be fine for some applications but this is mostly useful for *Editor plugins*.

Comment: I was actually wondering how do they do that without creating a new object for each parameter. I guess it doesn't... Feels like a waste to use it now.

Comment: It was poorly made but it is not a total waste. It's good for Editor plugin. You can use it for Editor plugin but not for your actual game/app. Now, you know why you are not supposed to use `GUILayoutOption` or anything that requires the `OnGUI` function in Unity. A new UI system was introduced to remove this problem but `GUILayoutOption` is still there for Editor plugins.

Comment: I actually made an Edit on how to improve that. The only thing that can't be improved now is the `param` keyword. Happy coding!